# Inequalities Multiplication

Tags: calculus, inequality

I know that I can add 2 inequalities, also know that I can multiply inequalities by a positive value and the inequalities does not flip. 
However is there a proof to multiplying two inequalities ? is it ok to do ?

Consider : $ a,b,c,d>0 $

$\left(a>b\right)\land(c>d)\overset{?}{\rightarrow}ac>bd$

Is it true due to multiplication? (I suspect not, but couldn't find out myself)
Is there a proof that using ordered field axioms ?

Answer (score 3):

It is indeed  true if all numbers are positive: from $a>b$, you deduce first $ac>bc$ since $c>0$. From $c>d$, you get, since $b>0$, $bc>bd$. Whence the result by transitivity.